# Boolean is always false even if I impose true

Tags: iphone, objective-c, boolean, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIView where before I use UILongPressGestureRecognizer and then I use UIPanGestureRecognizer. To UIPanGestureRecognizer I get a message about the pressure of UILongPressGestureRecognizer but my app doesn't take the boolean, this is always false even if I impose true. How can I do?

```
 -(IBAction)longGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{


   if(fromRiga ==0){
    if ([gestureRecognizer state]==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        self.inLongPress = YES;
        self.view.backgroundColor =[UIColor darkGrayColor];
        gestureRecognizer.allowableMovement=200;

      }else if([gestureRecognizer state]==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        self.inLongPress = NO;
      }
}

 - (IBAction)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
  {
    NSLog(@"inLongPress is %@", self.inLongPress ? @"YES": @"NO");
  }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pan recognizer triggers immediately when you touch the view and checks the movement since that moment. Long press recognizer triggers always much later then pan recognizer (after the *long* period ends). I suspect that the `panGesture` is always called before `longGesture`. Maybe the pan recognizer is cancelling long press recognizer entirely.

You should check what happens by adding more `NSLog` statements.

```
-(IBAction)longGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"Long gesture");

    if (fromRiga == 0){
        if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
            self.inLongPress = YES;
            self.view.backgroundColor =[UIColor darkGrayColor];
            gestureRecognizer.allowableMovement=200;

            NSLog(@"Long gesture began, self.iLongPress = %@", self.iLongPress ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        } else if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            self.inLongPress = NO;
            NSLog(@"Long gesture ended, self.iLongPress = %@", self.iLongPress ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"Pan gesture, self.iLongPress = %@", self.iLongPress ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
```

Comment: Long gesture began = YES; Long gesture ended = NO; Pan gesture =NO;

Comment: Well, that tells everything you wanted to know. Panning is handled after long gesture, maybe it even cancels long gesture.